# Sum of binomial coefficients with index divisible by 4

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-numbers, binomial-coefficients

I am trying to obtain a closed form expression for 
$\sum {n \choose 4k}$

I am trying to use the binomial expansion of $(1 + i)^n$ and $(1 - i)^n$.
$$(1 + i)^n + (1 - i)^n = 2\left(\sum {n \choose 4k} -\sum {n \choose 4k + 2}\right)$$ Stuck at this now. I can't come up with a way to simplify the second term on RHS. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Brute-force on the small N and find this sequence on the OEIS?

Comment: https://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C2%2C6%2C16%2C36%2C72%2C136%2C256%2C496%2C992%2C2016%2C4096%2C8256%2C16512%2C32896%2C&language=english&go=Search  - your sequence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After posting this question, it struck me that

RHS =  $4\sum {n \choose 4k} -2\sum {n \choose 4k} -2\sum {n \choose 4k + 2}) = 4\sum {n \choose 4k} - 2 \sum {n \choose 2k} = 4\sum {n \choose 4k} - 2 * 2^{n - 1} = 4\sum {n \choose 4k} - 2^{n} \implies \sum {n \choose 4k} = \frac{(1 + i)^n + (1 - i)^n + 2^n}{4}$

Answer (score 3):

We have the followings :

$$(1+1)^n=\binom n0+\binom n1+\binom n2+\binom n3+\binom n4+\binom n5+\cdots$$
$$(1-1)^n=\binom n0-\binom n1+\binom n2-\binom n3+\binom n4-\binom n5+\cdots$$
$$(1+i)^n=\binom n0+\binom n1i-\binom n2-\binom n3i+\binom n4+\binom n5i-\cdots$$
$$(1-i)^n=\binom n0-\binom n1i-\binom n2+\binom n3i+\binom n4-\binom n5i-\cdots$$

Adding these gives
$$(1+1)^n+(1-1)^n+(1+i)^n+(1-i)^n=4\left(\binom n0+\binom n4+\binom n8+\cdots\right)$$
I think that you can continue from here.

Comment: I came up with a slightly different way to approach this. But your way of visualizing is helpful as well.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\left.\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}{n \choose 4k}
\,\right\vert_{\ n\ \in\ \mathbb{N}_{\large n\ \geq\ 0}} & =
\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}{n \choose k}{1^{k} + \pars{-1}^{k} + \ic^{k} + \pars{-\ic}^{k} \over 4}
\\[5mm] & =
{1 \over 4}\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}{n \choose k}\pars{1}^{k} +
{1 \over 4}\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}{n \choose k}\pars{-1}^{k} +
{1 \over 2}\,\Re\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}{n \choose k}\ic^{k}
\\[5mm] & =
{1 \over 4}\pars{1 + 1}^{n} + {1 \over 4}\bracks{1 + \pars{-1}}^{n} +
{1 \over 2}\,\Re\pars{1 + \ic}^{n}
\\[5mm] & =
2^{n - 2} + {1 \over 4}\,\delta_{n0} + 
{1 \over 2}\,\Re\bracks{\root{1^{2} + 1^{2}}\expo{\ic\arctan\pars{1/1}}}^{n}
\\[5mm] & =
2^{n - 2} + {1 \over 4}\,\delta_{n0} +
{1 \over 2}\,\Re\bracks{2^{1/2}\expo{\ic\pi/4}}^{n}
\\[5mm] & =
\bbx{2^{n - 2} + {1 \over 4}\,\delta_{n0} +
2^{n/2 - 1}\cos\pars{n\pi \over 4}}
\end{align}

> Note tat it yields the *correct value* when $\ds{n = 0}$.

Comment: What is $\delta$ here?

Comment: @YiFan $\displaystyle\texttt{Kronecker Delta}$: $\displaystyle \delta_{n0} = 1$ if $\displaystyle n = 0$ and $\displaystyle = 0$ otherwise.