# Sum of binomial coefficient with both the upper and lower index being multiple of 4

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

There is [a nice proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2005038/1618) on MSE which shows that for $n \ge 1$,
$$
\sum_{k = 0}^{n}{4n \choose 4k} =
{1 \over 4}\left[\left(-1\right)^{n}\, 2^{2n + 1} + 16^{n}\right]
$$

I wonder if there is a more combinatorial proof for this?

Comment: Yes! See _Third and Fourth Binomial Coefficients_ by Arthur Benjamin and Jacob Scott, available online at https://scholarship.claremont.edu/hmc_fac_pub/124/.

Comment: When $n = 0$, LHS $= 1$ while RHS $= 3/4$ !!!.

Comment: @FelixMarin It is correct for all $n\ge 1$. To make it correct for $n=0$, change the RHS to $\frac14[2(-4)^n+16^n+0^n]$.

Comment: $\displaystyle\sum_{k = 0}^{n}{4n \choose 4k} =
{1 \over 4}\left[\left(-1\right)^{n}\, 2^{2n + 1} + 16^{n} + \delta_{n0}\right] $